# VBA SQL (MariaDB) - Query SELECT * duplicates first row, and miss last one

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, database

I have an issue while trying to get every line from a table in my database. In VBA when requesting the table with 'SELECT * FROM companies;', the results duplicates the first row, and remove the last one. As a result, I have 3 records, which corresponds to the real number of records in my DB, but instead of having 1, 2 and 3, I have 1, 1 and 2.

Any idea?

You can see here Database records for table 'companies', when requesting 'SELECT * FROM companies': [DB Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaEPF.png)

You can see here the result of the same request in Excel/VBA using the following code:

```html
sqlQuery = "SELECT ALL * FROM companies;"
rsDB.Open sqlQuery, conDB, adOpenDynamic

Do While Not rsDB.EOF
    For Each col In rsDB.GetRows
        Debug.Print col
    Next
Loop
```

Results: [VBA request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/791H6.png)

Would love to get any piece of advice on this issue!
The fun fact is that if I try to select only one column of the table, such as 'idCompany', then I have the result '1, 2, 3' with VBA, which is fine. The real issue only appears when using '*'.

Thanks a lot for your time,

--- EDIT
The connection string used to connect to the DB:

```html
Set conDB = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsDB = New ADODB.recordSet
Set rsDBCol = New ADODB.recordSet
conDB.connectionString = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};" _
    & "SERVER=s-mypricing-1;" _
    & "DATABASE=db_pricing;" _
    & "PORT=3306" _
    & "UID=user;" _
    & "PWD=pwd;" _
    & "OPTION=3"

conDB.Open
rsDB.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rsDBCol.CursorLocation = adUseServer
```

Comment: For each column in a row you are fetching the next record.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to test, but I suspect you need this instead:

```
rsDB.MoveFirst
Do While Not rsDB.EOF
    For Each fld In rsDB.Fields
        Debug.Print fld.Name & ": " & fld.Value
    Next
    rsDB.MoveNext
Loop
```

When you iterate an ADO recordset, the object itself represents a current row. So you refer to the Fields of the current row to get the columns. And the properties of each field to get descriptive information about that cell (name of column, value in cell).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and the time you spent on it.

I've already tried something like this, unsuccessfully.

I've tried again with your proposition, and I get the same result, unfortunately... First row is duplicated, last one removed. Thus, record 1 appears twice, record 3 0 time.

That's actually really hard to understand why, as I totally agree with your reasoning.

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Through the comments we learned that the issue is related to opening the recordset with `adOpenDynamic` mode. What follows is code that should represent a working case for MaraiaDB.

```
Set conDB = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsDB = New ADODB.recordSet
Set rsDBCol = New ADODB.recordSet
conDB.connectionString = "DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};" _
    & "SERVER=s-mypricing-1;" _
    & "DATABASE=db_pricing;" _
    & "PORT=3306" _
    & "UID=user;" _
    & "PWD=pwd;" _
    & "OPTION=3"

conDB.Open
rsDB.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rsDBCol.CursorLocation = adUseServer
sqlQuery = "SELECT ALL * FROM companies;"
With rsDB.Open(sqlQuery, conDB)
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fld In .Fields
                Debug.Print fld.Name & ": " & fld.Value
            Next

            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    .Close
End With

conDB.Close
```

Comment: Hi JackSlash, thanks for your answer & time!

It actually doesn't work, because it tries to get fields in an empty recordset when finishing the loop....
Well to be honest, that's the first time I encounter such an issue. I've never had this before while using Access or other SQL bases. It's maybe due to MariaDB...

I still have the solution to get all the ids using 'SELECT idCompany FROM companies' and then get '*' for each id, but it's far from being optimal...

Comment: If you got to the EOF record, did you see the missing #3 record right before that?

Comment: Nop...
Actually, I've tried many things and figured out that as long as I select only one element in my query, then I have the expected dataset. But if I select more than one parameter in myquery, then I have this same bug everytime: duplication of the first line, missing last one...

Comment: That's crazy town. It sounds like you are using the wrong database driver. Can you add your connection string to the main question so we can see how you are connecting to the DB?

Comment: Just added the connection string and parameters to the main question, thanks for your time!

Also it looks like the ODBC works, as when I try to directly link Excel with the DB using 'DATA', 'Get Data', 'From other sources' and then 'ODBC' and I select my MariaDB ODBC connector, it works perfectly: I can see the table with every rows.

Comment: It seems like the issue comes from the 'adOpenDynamic' at the end of my requrests. Without it, it works

Comment: Okay I updated the answer so that if some other MariaDB user comes along they can see an example to pull from. I can't test it. Does this look correct to you?